# Count number of special characters in name columns across all tables in database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find columns with 'name' in their title and count the number of records in them which have numbers or special characters (which makes them invalid). I want to apply this to all the tables and columns in my database.

My code is:

```
SELECT DB_Name() AS DatabaseName
    ,s.[name] AS SchemaName
    ,t.[name] AS TableName
    ,c.[name] AS ColumnName
    ,COUNT(c.name) As InvalidNameCnt
    ,'[' + DB_Name() + ']' + '.[' + s.name + '].' + '[' + T.NAME + ']' AS FullQualifiedTableName
    ,d.[name] AS DataType
FROM sys.schemas s
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types d ON c.user_type_id = d.user_type_id
    WHERE c.NAME LIKE '%name%'
    AND [DBName].[SystemName].[TableName].[ColumnName] NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%';
```

My code isn't working at the moment as it throws a message saying that the multi-part identifier for the last line can't be found, any solutions please?

Comment: You would need dynamic SQL for this.  Requiring that all columns with "name" in their name have a digit is very curious to me.

Comment: I don't want columns with 'name' to have a digit, I want to count the number of records in those columns which have numbers or special characters in them.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
SELECT DB_Name() AS DatabaseName,
s.[name] AS SchemaName,
t.[name] AS TableName,
c.[name] AS ColumnName,
COUNT(c.name) As InvalidNameCnt,
'[' + DB_Name() + ']' + '.[' + s.name + '].' + '[' + T.NAME + ']' AS 
 FullQualifiedTableName,
d.[name] AS DataType
FROM sys.schemas s
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types d ON c.user_type_id = d.user_type_id
WHERE c.NAME LIKE '%name%'
AND c.name NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'
group by s.[name] ,t.[name],c.[name],d.[name]
```